# How to prevent Powershell not showing script processing data

Tags: powershell, backend

I have created a powershell script for updating SharePoint List. When i run it shows all the backend processing to the console for example all the list schema info. I want it only show script created Out put (The only output with Write-Host) and not out of the box backend processing. Is there any command available to prevent that?

it shows counting like below when I use .add method of ArrayList where ever in script

```
0
1
2
3
```

and it shows List XML Schema when i store List items in some variable in the script like below:

```
Sealed                      : False
Version                     : 28
DisplayFormTemplateName     : DocumentLibraryForm
EditFormTemplateName        : DocumentLibraryForm
NewFormTemplateName         : DocumentLibraryForm
NewFormUrl                  : 
MobileNewFormUrl            : 
EditFormUrl                 : 
MobileEditFormUrl           : 
DisplayFormUrl              : 
MobileDisplayFormUrl        : 
Id                          : 0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39009893A4DD0A05487AAE05EAE8D183333C003933922476541344B8A065CBACE8178D
ReadOnly                    : False
Name                        : NewsPage
NameResource                : Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserResource
FeatureId                   : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Description                 : Used to create news articles.
JSLink                      : 
DescriptionResource         : Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserResource
Hidden                      : False
```

Comment: The output you're talking about could be a number of things from stdout output from applications, verbose, warning or the error stream. It would be helpful to see the code.

Comment: If the output is coming from a Windows command line program you can redirect its output. But as Adam indicated an incomplete question will get an incomplete answer. Please review the info on submitting questions in the SO help center.

Comment: Generally just pipe to Out-Null to get rid of the output.

Comment: Out-null works for me, Thanks--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some .Net Methods and external programs output their exit code and other output to stdout.

You can either add the void keyword to the arraylist "Add" command or pipe it to Out-Null

```
$MyList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
1..10 | % { $MyList.Add($_) } # outputs 0 to 9

1..10 | % { [void]$MyList.Add($_) } # no output
1..10 | % { $MyList.Add($_) | Out-Null } # no output
```